# git pull is not working on msysgit client?

Tags: windows, git, msysgit, pull

I am using msysgit client, I am able to fetch,push but when I try to pull it shows

```
git: 'pull' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

I tried for `git --exec-path` and it gives `C:\git-client/libexec/git-core`, this path exists but still I am not able to pull. Any idea?

Comment: Did you launch your git session through `C:\git-client\git-cmd.bat` or `git-bash.bat`? What version of msysgit are you using?

Comment: isnt Pull just a shorthand for fetch+merge? see if `git fetch` does anything first

Comment: @Uberfuzzy: thanx boss for your idea. Pull= fetch+merge. IDK why pull is not working but I got a workaround solution. Could you please post this as ans so I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in comment above:
`git pull` is (usually) shorthand for doing a `fetch` then `merge`.

Check that `git fetch` works first.

Further later research shows that this may be a bug in a specific version of msysgit, https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=249  So try upgrading that also (always prudent advice).

Additionally, a few googles for "`git: 'pull' is not a git command`" turned up quite a few choices on various fixes, based on which platform you are working on, but most turned out to be a missing path to git-core, so also check those out.